# Logstash file input: registering json file grew but not taking data in some cases

Tags: json, elasticsearch, character-encoding, logstash, pyyaml

My config file is shown below:

```
input {
  file {
    codec => "json"
    path => "/home/data/*"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch{
    protocol => "http"
    host => "localhost"
    index => "data"
  }
}
```

When I download a .json file to the `data` directory, logstash will not receive the data or output to elasticsearch unless I first open the file and save it in gedit.

Running logstash with the `-vvv` flag shows no errors all I get when a file is put in that directory is

```
_discover_file: /home/data/*: new: /home/data/prediction1.json (exclude is []) {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/watch.rb", :line=>"126"}
_open_file: /home/data/prediction1.json: opening {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"98"}
/home/data/prediction1.json: staying at position 0, no sincedb {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"143"}
writing sincedb (delta since last write = 377) {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"177"}
/home/data/prediction1.json: file grew, old size 0, new size 3952 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/watch.rb", :line=>"81"}
```

This led me to believe that there may be a character encoding problem as the json file is created using `json.dumps` in python before reaching elasticsearch. I tried converting the data to yaml:

```
outfile.write(yaml.dump(json.dumps(data)))
```

which logstash accepts as plain text as it is now in the form:

```
'data:{ properties:
  { location:
  { here }}}'
```

after using sed and tr commands to convert this BACK to valid json logstash no longer accepts it unless saved through gedit!!!

Comment: `json.dumps()` generates a string. Writing out that string with `yaml.dump()` doesn't do a conversion, it only puts the single quotes around the string. (BTW you can just specify a stream as second parameter to `yaml.dump()`, no need to first stash that in a StringIO buffer and then write it out).

Comment: If the json file is as big as your example, can you use `od -c filename` on both the working and non-working version of the file and include the output in your post?

Comment: thanks Anthon, the `od -c filename` prints the entire json out?

Comment: Yes it does, but it shows the special characters that make the difference between the output you generate that is incorrect and what comes out of Gedit that is correct. Just copy ad paste the output into your post (and indicate what is what for the two versions)